# Does anyone have random encounter tables for 4th edition D&D?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools, tool-recommendation, encounter-tables

One of the big things missing from 4e for my style of play is a good set of random encounter tables.  Has anyone worked up a set of tables like you find in 1e (i.e., covers a variety of dungeon levels and terrains)?

Ideally, the wilderness tables would be level-independent with a variety of encounter types for each terrain (e.g., aerial, beast, monster, humanoid, etc.)

The dungeon tables would be level dependent, but with a range of encounter levels possible as results for any given dungeon/character level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The donjon 4e Random Encounter Generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/4e/encounter/) is a decent random encounter generator. It's not a table, per se, but it has terrain/plane filters and random attached treasure.

Comment: That is actually pretty great. I'll hold out a little more, just in case anyone else finds anything, but this meets my needs pretty well.

Comment: One weird thing about that generator is the treasure--I can't figure out what it's based on, and it seems really high.  Can anyone else figure out what's going on with it?

Comment: @Numenetics I randomly found this question and I'm loving the generator, but I'm also still trying to understand the treasure. lol

Answer (score 1):

I particularly recommend [Asmor's 4e Random Encounter Generator](http://www.asmor.com/scripts/4eEncounterGen/index.php). While you need to be careful about MM1 monsters (that generally suck) it's a great way to go "I need an encounter... stat!"

Answer (score 0):

The [Dungeon Construction Kit](http://story-games.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=10763) (DCK) is a system currently in playtest that generates a dungeon and the contents of the rooms on-the-fly as you explore the dungeon, and specifically designed to be used with D&D 4e. I haven't played it, but the people who I've talked to in the playtest groups rave about it.

It sounds like the random creature generation part (which uses a stack of cards rather than tables, but to the same effect) could be adapted for use in a regular 4e game. I'm not sure when it's going to be published, but I get the impression that its stabilised and the playtest phase is coming to an end. There's not very much out on the web about it so far, just the word-of-mouth that I've caught occasionally [on twitter](http://twitter.com/rafial/status/22150758293) and [at conventions](http://story-games.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=12347#Item_4).

So, something to keep an eye out for, perhaps.

Comment: That looks nice--I'll definitely keep an eye out.